# Unresolved identifier using segue when passing data

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I am using segue to pass data between two viewcontrollers and that should be easy enough, but for som reason I can`t see there I keep getting "Unresolved Identifier"

Her are some of the code that has to do with that function.

from ViewController 1

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{

@IBOutlet var panelWidthTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var panelHightTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var panelsWideTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var panelsHightTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var panelPitchTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var calculateButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var resultWithLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var resultHightLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var fillAllFieldsLabel: UILabel!

var pawidth:String!
var pahight:String!
var papitch:String!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    panelWidthTextField.text = pawidth
    panelHightTextField.text = pahight
    panelPitchTextField.text = pap itch
```

From Second ViewController

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DataBase: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate

{
@IBOutlet var makerTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var modelTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var stPanelWidthTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var stPanelHightTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var stPitchTextField: UITextField!

let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as!     AppDelegate).managedObjectContext


// Removes keyboard when touch outside edit field.
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
    view.endEditing(true)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

}

@IBAction func saveButton(sender: UIButton)
{
    let ed = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Ledinfo", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
    let model = Ledinfo(entity:ed!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:moc)

    model.manufactor = makerTextField.text
    model.model = modelTextField.text
    model.panelwidth = stPanelWidthTextField.text
    model.panelhight = stPanelHightTextField.text
    model.pitch = stPitchTextField.text

    do  {
        try moc.save()
        makerTextField.text = ""
        modelTextField.text = ""
        stPanelWidthTextField.text = ""
        stPanelHightTextField.text = ""
        stPitchTextField.text = ""
        Alert.show("Succsess", message: "Your Record Is Saved", vc: self)


    }
    catch _ as NSError
    {
        Alert.show("Failed", message: "Something Went Wrong", vc: self)
    }


}

@IBAction func searchButton(sender: UIButton)
{
    let ed = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Ledinfo", inManagedObjectContext: moc)

    let req = NSFetchRequest()
    req.entity = ed

    let cond = NSPredicate(format: "manufactor = %@", makerTextField.text!)
    req.predicate = cond


    do {

        let result = try moc.executeFetchRequest(req)

        if result.count > 0
        {
            let model = result[0] as! Ledinfo
            makerTextField.text = model.manufactor
            modelTextField.text = model.model
            stPanelWidthTextField.text = model.panelwidth
            stPanelHightTextField.text = model.panelhight
            stPitchTextField.text = model.pitch


        } else
        {

        Alert.show("Failed", message: "No Record Is Found", vc: self)

    }

    } catch _ as NSError!

    {
        Alert.show("Failed", message: "No Record Is Found" , vc: self)

    }

}

@IBAction func transfereButton(sender: UIButton) {

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if (segue.identifier == "transfereButton") {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController


        svc.pawidth = stPanelWidthTextField.text
        svc.pahight = stPanelHightTextField.text
        svc.papitch = stPitchTextField.text

                }
}


}
```

It can not find panelWidthTextField.text, panelHightTextField.text and panelPitchTextField.text as identifier.

I have check spelling and just can`t seem to be able to find what is missing.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: "It can not find panelWidthTextField" — we can't, neither. Where did you declare `panelWidthTextField`?

Comment: They are declared in first viewcontroller see updated code,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Segue" means, that in "prepareForSegue" method you set the property of ViewController to some data in your DataBase controller. In your example, this can be done like this:

```
svc.pawidth = someDataFromDataBaseWhichYouWantToPassToSecondVC
svc.pahight = someDataFromDataBaseWhichYouWantToPassToSecondVC
svc.papitch = someDataFromDataBaseWhichYouWantToPassToSecondVC
```

And then, you can manipulate this data from your ViewController class. 
You mistake that you are not passing the data from one VC to another, instead of that you are trying to set the property of 1stVC to another property of 1stVC, and there is no segue needed.

Comment: svc.pawidth = panelWidthTextField.text  -  padwith is the property of firstVC, and panelWidthTextField is the property of firstVC, what do you want to do?

Comment: I am trying to send data in a textfield from DataBase to a textfield in ViewController

Comment: can you update the code in DataBase controller? I can't see any textFields in you DataBase

Comment: At first, try add some print statement after if (segue.identifier == "transfereButton") { so you can check if that method is called

Comment: Does not seem like the method is called for a reason, not sure why. It only shows ViewController

Comment: so you can navigate between VC but the prepareForSegue isn't called? Check you segue identifier in the storyboard, and in code and make sure, that they are equal.

Comment: you can also check that video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTSDvsA1yuA , there are exactly what you want

Comment: Forgot to set the Segue identifier, all good now. Thanks for great help.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with segues. do you have 3 text fields in your `DataBase` class with names `panelWidthTextField`, `panelHightTextField` and `panelPithcTextField`? It's complaining about not being able to find those variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `performSegueWithIdentifier("transfereButton", sender: nil)` inside your `transfereButton` IBOutlet action to actually make the `prepareForSegue` to run.